# give all rows if IN clause is empty in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to filter users using country wise . `$country` is an array containing the name of countries. I want to run the query in such a way that if there is nothing in country then the query gives me all the rows. how can i acheive this.

I am doing this :

```
  "SELECT * from users where country IN('".implode("','",$country)."')";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Check `if count($country)>0`

Comment: can u explain a bit more

Comment: @Sadikhasan I got many filters like countries. Then i have to use ample amount of if else conditions

Comment: @Fluffeh yup you are right :) deleting that comment it does not make sense to add `1=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

if($country) {
    $sql .= " WHERE country IN('" . implode("','", $country) . "')";
}
```

Comment: I think the OP assumes that there is data in the array each time - but to only return the entire set if no matches are found in the array.

Answer (score 0):

For each filter item just check if it is NULL (i.e. don't filter the results based on this) or if it is equal/in:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE ('".implode("','",$country)."' IS NULL OR country IN('".implode("','",$country)."'))
AND ($forename IS NULL OR forename = $forename)
```